# GPS Shapefile into geodatabase feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, enterprise-geodatabase, point

I have a set of points I collected (shapefile) that I want to import into an existing sde feature class, what is the best method to do this?

Comment: Right click the shapefile in ArcCatalog, select Export, and navigate to your geodatabase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two basic methods (among others):

***1). Copy/paste within ArcMap***

- Start an edit session in ArcMap, editing the SDE featureclass that you want to add the new points to.
- Add the new points shapefile to the table of contents.
- Select all of the new shapefile points that you want to add to the SDE feature class (ensure that these are the only features selected).
- With the points selected and using the "edit arrow" right-click anywhere in the map and choose "Copy" then "Paste" from the context menu. When you choose paste, you should see a drop-down box listing all editable point layers - from this drop down, choose your SDE feature class.
- Save your edits & end your edit session

***2). Append tool***

- In ArcCatalog, browse through the "System" toolbox to the "Append" tool (it's in "ArcToolbox" > "Data Management" > "General").
- Double-click the tool. The tool's wizard will guide you through specifying the "Input dataset" (your shapefile) and the "Target dataset" (your SDE feature class).
- If the two sets of data do not have the same or similar field names, you will have to do some work in the "Field Map" window. See the ArcGIS help documentation for more on that.

Comment: Hi Matt, thats the thing, I am not making a new SDE feature class, I want to import them into an existing feature class - sorry if I didn't make that clearer in the initial question